# Using Geostatistical Analyst Explore Tools in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, geostatistical-analyst

Does anyone know where the Geostatistical Analyst Explore Tools are in ArcGIS Pro?

I just can't find them. There's an option for seeing some of them by right-clicking the interpolated layer but it's not showing Trend Analysis, Semivariogram and Crossvariance.

In ArcMap there was also an option to compare 2 interpolated layers. Not in Pro anymore.

[image]

Comment: Have you reviewed https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/analysis/geostatistical-analyst/get-started-with-geostatistical-analyst-in-arcgis-pro.htm?

Comment: Thanks, I have; but there's nothing there about these tools in particular.